How can display the result of my HTML/JS code?
I wanted to create Js calculator,so I got a problem with displaying the results of my code on textarea.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function handleClick(event)
            {
                const action = event.target.dataset.action;
                const area = document.getElementById("area");
                area.value += String.fromCharCode(action);
            }

            let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("but");

            [...buttons].forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click',handleClick))
            
        </script>
        <textarea row = "10" col = "10" id="area" placeholder = "Here will be your answear..."></textarea>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "49">1</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "50">2</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "51">3</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "52">4</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "53">5</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "54">6</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "55">7</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "56">8</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "57">9</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "48">0</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "187">+</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "189">-</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "56">*</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "191">/</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "187">=</button>
        <button class = "but" data-action = "67">C</button>
    
    </body>
</html>

Thanks for your help!
I tried to add const area because I thought that it will help my code to understand where the result must be displayed...

What's the actual problem? Is there an error in your dev console?

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

document.getElementsByClassName("but") - There are no such elements when that code executes.  They're added after.  Move the script to the bottom of the page instead.  (Rolled back my edit as it quietly corrected the problem.)

My main problem is that I wanted to write a calculator in JavaScript, but I ran into the fact that my JavaScript code does not display the result in the textarea field.The idea of ​​my calculator was that the user of the site could click on the buttons, the tag - buttons, and with each click on these buttons, the text field ("Here will be your answear...") would change, adding the button pressed by the user to the screen, and then in the same field the result of the mathematical equation would be displayed.You can see an example of my idea if you type in Google the phrase - Google calculator!

Your function is updating the string based on the button pushed, but never attempts to calculate anything.
